# METEOR Iron router with no template?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I've created a new meteor project called TEST and ended up with:

```
test.html
test.css
test.js
```

Now I installed the iron router and would like that the route page "/" shows directly to the test.html

Now I don't have a template on that page... it's just standard HTML layout:

```
<head>
...
</head>

<body>
...
</body>
```

Still Iron router requires a template configurtion e.g.

```
Router.route('/', {
    name: 'home',
    template: 'home'
});
```

So how can I point to that one SINGLE page?

[EDIT]

I tried with:

Router.route('/', {
        name: 'body',
        template: 'body'
    });

and ended up duplicating my test.html page (like replicate itself for 2 times) lol :D

Answer (score 1):

Did you try just `Router.route('/')`?

I think Iron:router will render all `<body></body>` tags (they are merged in Meteor) by default, i.e. if no template is set in route configuration.